# If a statement is not true, must its negation be true?

Tags: logic

I've encountered a textbook problem that's telling me to prove an iff statement or its negation.

Consider the statement:

$P \iff Q$

In my scenario, I have that:

$P \implies Q$ but it's not the case that $Q \implies P$

The negation of the original statement is $P \iff \neg Q$.

but clearly, this is not true because $P \implies Q$.

I am simply asking if my logic is correct, and both the statement and its negation are false.

Comment: According to the post I linked, the negation is `no cloud <=> rain`. The negation of $P \iff Q$ is $P \iff \neg Q$

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to `rain => clouds AND clouds => rain` (and not to what you wrote).

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb what did I write I was stating the fact that `rain => clouds` is true and `clouds => rain` is not (real truth values). I'm saying the iff I'm facing is similar, where one way is True but the converse is not.

Comment: @Surb I am pretty sure what you say is the same statement. I'm referring to the accepted answer from post I linked.

Comment: @Surb This is not the negation. In fact those statements are equivalent. The negation of $A\iff B$ is $A\ xor B$.

Comment: That $A$ and $not\ A$ cannot be both true is what we call consistency. That one of $A$ and $not\ A$ must be true is what we call the law of the excluded middle. This law is generally accepted and important for many important results of mathematics.

Comment: @Peter The first thing you mention is the law of [non-contradiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_noncontradiction#:~:text=In%20logic%2C%20the%20law%20of,p%20is%20not%20the%20case%22). Whereas [consistency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency#Definition) is about collections of axioms, or theories, I believe?

Comment: @freakish A statement cannot be equivalent to its negation.

Comment: @Peter can you explain what I am seeing? It seems like neither is true.

Comment: @CM-rings A system is called consistent if it is impossible that we can derive both $A$ and $not\ A$ for a statement $A$. I do not understand the comment.

Comment: @Peter The comment is that I think what you called consistency is actually called the law of non-contradiction.

Comment: Negation is not controversial at all: the negation of a true statement is a false one.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA for my example, I am asking about…

Comment: In this case it seems the IFF statement and its negation are both false. Is this correct? That is my question.

Comment: No, an IFF is true when both have the same truth vue. Thus, it will be false when they have different truth values.

Comment: So the if and only if is false, but the negation is also false @MauroALLEGRANZA. Can you tell me about this?

Comment: Let us recap it: If P⟹Q is true and Q⟹P is false, then P⟺Q is false, simply because P⟺Q amounts to P⟹Q **and** Q⟹P. And yes, the negation of P⟺Q amounts to P⟺¬Q (check it with truth table). BUT this one is not the same as P⟹Q  true and Q⟹P false, because the negation of P⟹Q is not P⟹¬Q. This is the reason why your conclusion does not hold.

Answer (score 3):

The statement $\ P\Rightarrow Q\ $ does not necessarily contradict $\ P\Leftrightarrow\neg\,Q\ $. You've specified that $\ Q\Rightarrow P\ $ is false, and this can be the case *only* when $\ P\ $ is false and $\ Q\ $ is true, and in that case both $\ P\Rightarrow Q\ $ and $\ P\Leftrightarrow\neg\,Q\ $ are true.

You need to keep in mind that the symbol $\ \Rightarrow\ $ represents [*material implication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional) which has some properties that will appear counterintuitive if you confuse it with other forms of implication more commonly used outside formal logic. The proposition $\ P\Rightarrow R\ ,$ for instance, is always true whenever $\ P\ $ is false, regardless of what the proposition $\ R\ $ (or its truth value) is. In particular, both $\ P\Rightarrow Q\ $ and $\ P\Rightarrow\neg\,Q\ $ are true if and only if $\ P\ $ is false.

Comment: Re: Material implication and common usage. Consider the implication $P \implies Q$. Suppose the antecedent $P$ is true. From the usual truth table, if  the implication is true, then the consequent $Q$ must be true (the detachment rule). If the consequent $Q$ is false, then the implication must be false (the counter-example rule). These two rules sum up the common usage of implication. Rarely in daily discourse do we give much consideration to the implications of propositions known to be false.

Comment: ... In very technical arguments like mathematical proofs, however, we often consider such implications. Again, from the usual truth table for implication $P\implies Q$, if the antecedent $P$ is false, then the implication $P\implies Q$ will be true regardless of the truth value of the consequent $Q$ (the vacuous truth rule).

Comment: @DanChristensen the point is that implication is seen as stronger in natural usage. Most people don’t wake up, see that it’s cloudy and that it’s Tuesday, and then conclude “If it’s cloudy, then it’s Tuesday.” That is, the truth or falsehood of the propositional atoms of an implication are really only the truth-maker(s) for that implication in the context of Classical Logic.

Comment: @PW_246 It wouldn't be very useful, but they could rightly conclude that "if it's cloudy, then it's Friday." It might raise a few eyebrows, but it would not lead to any inconsistencies or errors in its acceptance as true at that instant in time. It makes no predictions about the future or claims about the past.

Comment: @DanChristensen yes, but that’s hardly what implication means in general.

Comment: @PW_246 Implication and causality are often confused (e.g. "smoking causes cancer" being equated to "smoking implies cancer"). Also, certain features of logical implication (e.g. vacuous truth) are rarely used in daily discourse, but they are apparently not inconsistent with more commonly used features (e.g. detachment and counter-examples).

Comment: @DanChristensen I never claimed that implication requires causality. The point is that at minimum, natural language conditionals are just not analyzable purely in terms of a case analysis of the truth or falsehood of its constituent propositions, but rather capture a notion similar to entailment, but without the need to be tied to a specific theory/logic/whatever.

Comment: AFAICT natural language conditionals involving true-or-false propositions in the present tense (or other fixed timeframe) are adequately modelled with material conditionals. Do you have a counter-example in mind?

Comment: Philosophers have been debating these issues. since at least [as early as McColl (1908)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/).  I didn't intend to take any side in that debate.  One suggestion, however, has been that "implication" in natural language means something closer to a form of entailment than to material implication—not necessarily [logical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_consequence) or [linguistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entailment_(linguistics)), but more in the sense that the consequent follows from the antecedent by a valid informal argument.

Comment: It therefore seemed to me that this might have been the reason for the OP's misunderstanding that $\ P\Rightarrow Q\ $ necessarily contradicted $\ P\Leftrightarrow\neg\,Q\ .$

Answer (score 0):

> Consider the statement:
>
> $P \iff Q$

So, you are assuming that: $~(P\implies Q)\land (Q\implies P)$

> In my scenario, I have that:
>
> $P \implies Q$ but it's not the case that $Q \implies P$

Now, you are assuming that: $~(P \implies Q) \land \neg (Q\implies P)$.

This leads to the  obvious contradiction: $~(Q \implies P) \land \neg (Q\implies P)$

You can stop here.